# Externally browsing an Embedded JavaDB deployment

Tags: java, database, browser, embedded-database, javadb

I created and deployed a javadb-powered portable swing application.
The app creates the javadb database folder as expected if it doesn't exist.

Now the time may come when I would need to browse that embedded database folder like I would using Mysql Query Browser or something. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Any JDBC base query tool should be able to connect to the database as long as your application is not running.

A list of tools is available in the Derby wiki:

http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby#GUI_Tools